# Extend QPixmap on the right side without modify the content

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

For a given QPixmap with 200x200 dimension, I want to extend it with 50px (transparent) on the right side, without scaling the existing content.

Is this possible on QPixmap or with any Qt helper class?

Answer (score 2):

Just paint the original pixmap onto a new, extended one...

```
QPixmap original_pixmap = ...
QPixmap new_pixmap(original_pixmap.width() + 50, original_pixmap.height());
new_pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter painter(new_pixmap);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, original_pixmap);
```